# Create a custom pivot table off two different pivot tables

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, powerpivot

Suppose you have the following 2 tables from 2 different sources of data

Table 1

[image]

Table 2

[image]

I want to create a custom pivot table off these two tables, which will look like the following

[image]

Note that the two common values between table 1 and table 2 are the account names and category names. There are 2 levels of rows in the tables, account name and category name.

Not every account name in table 2 will show up in table 1 and not every category in table 2 will show up in table 1. There will be null/missing values between table 2 and 1.

Table 1 has filters applied to it, mainly removing duplicate accounts and for a specific date range. Table 2 has a filter for specific date range. There are 5 different kinds of transactions and table 2 is filtered to show only filled transactions. There are 12 sheets in my table with this exact same format, except each sheet is a different month in 2021. I want to put table 3 in a separate sheet, along with other custom pivot tables, bringing the # of sheets in workbook to 24